# How can I check what units I may recruit in a province?

Tags: rome-2-total-war

When I select a province I don't know how to check what units I may recruit in that region. When I have a general and choose to recruit units I can see all available. Is there a similar view when I don't have a general in the province?

Of course I could see what military buildings I have and see the tooltip for it, but then I can't see the stats for the units.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the unit building to see the names of the units you can recruit, then the encyclopedia (help) to check that unit stats, or even compare them.